# What is a formal definition of series?

Tags: analysis

Is there a formal definition for series?
For example, cardinal sum has a formal definition such that $\sum a_i$ = $\bigcup a_i$.
Is there any clear definition for series of real or complex number?

The definition on my book is the sum of $a_0 + ... + a_n$. This seems very intuitive to me so i don't like it..

I tried to define series such that $\gamma(0) = a_0$ and $\gamma(n+1) = f_n(\gamma(n))$ where $f_n(x) = x+ a_n$

Since $f_n ≠ f_{n+1}$, i can't apply finite recurssion theorem. However it seems obvious that $\gamma$ is a function and unique. How do i prove the existence and uniqueness of $\gamma$?

---

I have proved that "If A is a set, 'c' a fixed point in A and $f_n : A →A$ a function for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists a unique function $\gamma : \mathbb{N} →A$ such that $\gamma(0) = c$ and $\gamma(n+1) = f_n(\gamma(n))$. This is a bit generalized form of original finite recursion theorem.
Let $\alpha$ be a sequence. Let $f_n(x)=x+\alpha(n+1) : F→F$. (F denotes an arbitrary field here) Then by above theorem, we can construct $\gamma$. It can be easily checked that $\gamma(n)$ is a summation of $a_0,...,a_n$.

By the way, i've never said series is a 'finite summation'. Of course, series is a sequence..

Comment: Sure; look in any real analysis textbook.

Comment: @Qiaochu given a sequence {$a_n$}, $\sum a_n$ denotes $a_0$ + ... $a_n$, p59. PMA -Rudin

Comment: I think that definition is intuitively defined.. Is there any abstract one?

Comment: There is nothing non-rigorous about what Rudin says on page 59. What do you find unsatisfactory about it?

Comment: I rather want to define it by a recurssion theorem. Such as $\gamma (0) = a_0$ and $\gamma(n+1) = \gamma(n) + a_n+$

Comment: I don't know how to construct a function $f$ such that $f(\gamma(n)) = \gamma(n) + a_{n+1}$

Comment: Well, that's because there isn't such a function (consider what happens if $\gamma(n) = \gamma(m)$ but $a_{n+1} \neq a_{m+1}$).

Comment: Once again: to accept an answer less than 45 minutes after the question was asked has some questionable consequences.

Comment: @Katlus Please notice that $a_0+\ldots +a_n$ is **not** a series. You should probably write $\{a_0+\ldots + a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ or something alike.

Comment: @Siminore: ...Which would be a sequence, and not a series (as you are perfectly aware, I know...).

Comment: Well, I was taught that a series is just the sequence built by summation of the first terms of a given sequence.

Comment: @Siminore: Then every sequence would be a series. This might be the reason why one keeps in mind both sequences (the increments and the partial sums) to define a series.

Comment: Yes, indeed $a_n = s_{n}-s_{n-1}$, and there is a one-to-one correspondence between sequences and series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any sequence $(a_0,a_0,\ldots)$ of real numbers. Define a function $r$ on finite sequences of real numbers such that if $s$ has length $n-1>0$, $r(s)$ is the last value of $s$ plus $a_n$. If the length of $s$ is $0$ (which we allow), then $r(s)=a_0$. The (countable) recursion theorem gives you a unique sequence $(b_0,b_1\ldots)$ such that $b_{n+1}=b_n+a_{n+1}$ and that defines your series. Note that the recursion is allowed to depend on all finite sequence of values.

There are two things you might think are not rigorous here: The "length" and the "last value". A finite sequence is a function with domain being a finite ordinal. This ordinal *is* the length, which is therefore well-defined. the elements of an ordinal are again ordinals and the value at the largest such ordinal in the domain is the "last value".

Comment: Sorry that i changed my question while you were posting it .. Would you please tell me how do i define such $b$? The finite recurssion theorem i know has $f$ doesn't depend on its 'input' value..(described in my edited question)

Comment: You cannot use the recursion theorem you mentioned, which is why use a stronger version in which one takes finite sequences as inputs. It is a special version of the general recursion theorem you find in set theory books.

Comment: I have proved that "If A is a set, 'c' a fixed point in A and $f_n : A →A$ a function for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists a unique function $\gamma : \mathbb{N} →A$ such that $\gamma(0) = c$ and $\gamma(n+1) = f_n(\gamma(n))$.

Comment: which is a little generalized form of original finite recursion theorem. With this I have defined series as a sequence and it works fine. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{i=1}^2a_i=a_1+a_2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^na_i+a_{n+1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$ if the limit exists.

Comment: I do not like this definition. I believe that a series is **a sequence**. You write that a series is **the limit** of a sequence. This might generate some confusion, because you should not even speak of the series $\sum_n (-1)^n$.

Comment: I am quite happy to speak of the series $\sum_n(-1)^n$; I speak of it as a divergent series. But if you don't like that, define $\sum^{\infty}a_i$ to be the sequence $(\sum^1a_i,\sum^2a_i,\sum^3a_i,\dots)$.

Comment: Well, we should probably agree on the most economic definition.

Comment: @Siminore, the most economic definition is "six".

Comment: I can't understand the last comment, sorry.

Comment: @Siminore, that's OK, I probably misunderstood your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, a series is a pair of sequences $(x_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ and $(S_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ such that $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nx_k$ for every $n\geqslant0$ (with the obvious modifications for sequences and series indexed by $n\geqslant i$ with $i\ne0$).

Comment: I think this is a formal but correct definition.

Comment: @Siminore: Yes, formal (whatever that means) *and* correct.

Comment: Of course :-) I wrote that because the OP seems to prefer a rather "colloquial" definition. By the way, His/her textbook states that a series is a **finite** sum!

Comment: @Siminore: Yep, you are right that there are definitely some serious misconceptions at work here. Unfortunately, apart from that, I am not even sure of what the question is really...